# Use websocket in Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, windows, websocket, webview

I am trying to load html page in my Flutter desktop app(MAC and Windows) using webivew plugin(webview_cef ). Currently am able to load the html page and display the required content. Now I need to send data to and from Flutter to JS/html and vice-versa. I am thinking to use websocket to transfer data between Flutter and JS/html . My flutter will act as server and JS/html would act as client.  The data that am planning to send from Flutter to JS/Html could be large data of image buffer in CMYK format. How do I achieve this using the available plugins in Flutter?

webview_cef is the package what I am currently using and community claims that it supports Flutter -JS bridge but its not working. Not able to even post a message from Flutter to JS and vice versa. So am thinking to use websocket

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.